# What $x$ satisfies $x^2 \equiv x \pmod{n}$ for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, solution-verification, chinese-remainder-theorem

$\textbf{Question}$:
Let $n$ be a positive integer. Determine, in terms of $n$, the number of
$x$ where $x \in {1,2,\ldots,n}$ for which $x^2 ≡ x \pmod n.$

$\textbf{My solution}$:
Let $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$. Now for each of the prime power we have two choices :

1. $p_i^{a_i} \mid x$, $\; $or,
2. $p_i^{a_i} \mid x-1$.

Then Chinese Remainder Theorem would make sure that these $n$ congruences result in one unique $x.$

Hence, our answer is $2^{\omega(n)}$ where $\omega(n)$ denotes the number of distinct prime factors of n.

I wanted to verify my answer and I would also appreciate any kind of remark.

Comment: Yes, same as in the linked dupe.

Comment: Anyway, your argument is correct.

Comment: @Jyrki I'll add that too (the general case is handled in the first link too, though less explicitly, but more generally, i.e. any polynomial $\in\Bbb Z[x],\,$ not only $\,x^2-x)$

Comment: Thanks @BillDubuque. I agree that it is a good idea to have a link to a case where polynomials are also discussed. Deleting the obsolete comment.

Comment: @Jyrki Yes, the more the merrier when it comes to good dupe links.